# Box2D, the b2AABB class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d, flashdevelop

I was watching a tutorial on youtube on using Box2D in AS3. The guy sets the size of the universe first and when writting the world variable, `world = new b2World(` FlashDevelop completes with **worldAABB:b2AABB**,gravity:b2Vec2,doSleep:Boolean);

In my project with the latests versions of FD and Box2D, when writting the same thing as above, FD doesn't complete with the b2AABB class and in the tutorials it does say his tutorials are a bit outdated.

Also, before this one I did follow other tutorials that didn't use b2AABB and didn't set universe size.

Is b2AABB class still used?

Answer (score 0):

b2AABB parameter is no longer necessary.

2.0 manual is out-dated as-well. Refer to [2.1a](http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.html#b2World%28%29) documentation instead.